# Is it possible to pass a true/false value to a ajax function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make a sorting function in ajax
but the sorting function can be enable or disable by the user 
I tried to pass a variable when user clicks a button, however the ajax 
still using the old variable 

Is it possible to  do it?

Here is my code

```
 var sort_or_not = "true";  
 function click_button_to_not_sort_test()
{sort_or_not = "false";}
//function to make my ajax not sort?
function approve_edit()
{

      $('#approve_table').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "paging":false, 
        "bPaginate":false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "scrollY":        300,
        "info": false, 
        //"bSort" : false,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
            { 'bSortable': sort_or_not,   //This is the variable that i want    to to passed from the button click 
              'aTargets': [ 0, 1, 2,3 ] 
            },
            { 'width': "15%", 
              'aTargets': [ 0, 2, 3]
            }
            ],
        "ajax": "approve_table.php?approve=1"
      });
```

Comment: I think you should use proper boolean and not string, I mean `true` / `false` instead of `"true"` / `"false"`.

Comment: Where is your ajax request?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul `"ajax": "approve_table.php?approve=1"` this means the library DataTable get values thanks to an ajax request. However, I do not think this matters here.

Comment: @Delgan Oh yes, thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @AdamYulok, If you're saying that *I tried to pass a variable when user clicks a button, however the ajax still using the old variable*, then you should set `cache: false` because then only it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `true` or `false` in quotes. So first lines should be:

```
var sort_or_not = true;
function click_button_to_not_sort_test() {
    sort_or_not = false;
}
```